# Cannot install vlc in ubuntu 13.10

Tags: installation, apt, 13.10, vlc

for some reasons I cannot instal VLC media player on my Ubuntu Gnome 13.10 32bit. I added the VideoLAN PPA repository and ran `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get install vlc`
Here's the log -

```
nisarg@nisarg-ThinkPad-T61:~$ sudo apt-get install vlc
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  liba52-0.7.4 libaacs0 libass4 libavcodec53 libavformat53 libavutil51
  libbluray1 libcddb2 libcrystalhd3 libdc1394-22 libdca0 libdirac-encoder0
  libdirectfb-1.2-9 libdvbpsi8 libdvdnav4 libdvdread4 libebml3 libfaad2
  libgsm1 libiso9660-8 libkate1 libmad0 libmatroska5 libmodplug1 libmpcdec6
  libmpeg2-4 libopus0 libpostproc52 libresid-builder0c2a libschroedinger-1.0-0
  libsdl-image1.2 libsdl1.2debian libsidplay2 libssh2-1 libswscale2 libtar0
  libts-0.0-0 libtwolame0 libupnp6 libva-x11-1 libva1 libvcdinfo0 libvlc5
  libvlccore5 libwebp4 libx264-123 libxcb-composite0 libxcb-keysyms1
  libxcb-randr0 libxcb-xv0 libzvbi-common libzvbi0 tsconf vlc-data vlc-nox
  vlc-plugin-notify vlc-plugin-pulse
Suggested packages:
  libbluray-bdj firmware-crystalhd libdvdcss2 debhelper opus-tools
  videolan-doc
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  liba52-0.7.4 libaacs0 libass4 libavcodec53 libavformat53 libavutil51
  libbluray1 libcddb2 libcrystalhd3 libdc1394-22 libdca0 libdirac-encoder0
  libdirectfb-1.2-9 libdvbpsi8 libdvdnav4 libdvdread4 libebml3 libfaad2
  libgsm1 libiso9660-8 libkate1 libmad0 libmatroska5 libmodplug1 libmpcdec6
  libmpeg2-4 libopus0 libpostproc52 libresid-builder0c2a libschroedinger-1.0-0
  libsdl-image1.2 libsdl1.2debian libsidplay2 libssh2-1 libswscale2 libtar0
  libts-0.0-0 libtwolame0 libupnp6 libva-x11-1 libva1 libvcdinfo0 libvlc5
  libvlccore5 libwebp4 libx264-123 libxcb-composite0 libxcb-keysyms1
  libxcb-randr0 libxcb-xv0 libzvbi-common libzvbi0 tsconf vlc vlc-data vlc-nox
  vlc-plugin-notify vlc-plugin-pulse
0 upgraded, 58 newly installed, 0 to remove and 7 not upgraded.
Need to get 16.7 MB of archives.
After this operation, 75.0 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
Get:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/videolan/stable-daily/ubuntu/ saucy/main vlc-data all 2.0.8+git20131025+r620-0~r13~ubuntu13.10.1 [4,967 kB]
Get:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/videolan/stable-daily/ubuntu/ saucy/main libvlccore5 i386 2.0.8+git20131025+r620-0~r13~ubuntu13.10.1 [384 kB]
Get:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/videolan/stable-daily/ubuntu/ saucy/main libvlc5 i386 2.0.8+git20131025+r620-0~r13~ubuntu13.10.1 [42.4 kB]
Get:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/videolan/stable-daily/ubuntu/ saucy/main vlc-nox i386 2.0.8+git20131025+r620-0~r13~ubuntu13.10.1 [2,084 kB]
Get:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/videolan/stable-daily/ubuntu/ saucy/main vlc i386 2.0.8+git20131025+r620-0~r13~ubuntu13.10.1 [1,078 kB]
Get:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/videolan/stable-daily/ubuntu/ saucy/main vlc-plugin-notify i386 2.0.8+git20131025+r620-0~r13~ubuntu13.10.1 [5,836 B]
Get:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/videolan/stable-daily/ubuntu/ saucy/main vlc-plugin-pulse i386 2.0.8+git20131025+r620-0~r13~ubuntu13.10.1 [18.2 kB]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy/universe libaacs0 i386 0.6.0-2     
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.92.176 80]
51% [Waiting for headers]
```

Now it doesn't move forward after this point. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Try installing it directly from the Ubuntu Software Center or simply get it [here](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/download-ubuntu.html). (Click Download for Ubuntu under Quick Install)

Comment: When downloading from the link you provided, I get an option to choose application, but instead of displaying a list of appilcaitons, it displays the following - http://s9.postimg.org/yajn1f7in/Screenshot_from_2013_10_31_21_32_48.png
Where do I find the required software with which I have to open the download file.
As for downloading from USC, it sticks to - 'Downloading 0 bytes of 8.1 MB'.
Some how VLC hates me :(

Answer (score 0):

Since your internet connection is working, try a different download server other than the main one:

1. Open the "Software and Updates" program.
2. Go to the "Ubuntu Software" tab (it might be selected by default).
3. In the "Download From" menu, change the server from "Main Server" to something else. If you want, select "Other . . . " and click the "Select Best Server" button to find the server that works best for your location.

Comment: Did as you directed, still gets stucks at the following line - After this operation, 74.8 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
Err http://mirror.its.dal.ca/ubuntu/ saucy/universe libaacs0 i386 0.6.0-2
  Connection failed [IP: 192.75.96.254 80]
0% [Waiting for headers]

Answer (score 0):

if you really want to do it by the Command line way :

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install vlc browser-plugin-vlc
```

more ways can be found [here](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/download-ubuntu.html)

Comment: Was facing the same problem when using aforementioned commands. I think its some problem with my Internet connection.

Comment: what error did you get exactly..did you add the "browser-plugin-vlc" part

Comment: Yes I did. Then some fine day I tried the command again and it worked!

Comment: kudos..good to hear that I could help.

Comment: and yes, please close the question if your problem was solved.